# Get highest value from a list with a lot of useless characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to get a value from a cell in Google Sheets which contains a list of values separated with commas.

Example:

> UC133 - 2019/01/10 2019/01/30, UC99 - 2018/11/29 2018/12/19, UC134 -
>   2019/06/01 2019/06/19, UC132 - 2018/12/20 2019/01/09

I would like to be able to get an output in a cell of "UC134", because 134 is "bigger" than UC99, UC132 and UC133.

I tried a lot of different functions and formulas but I am unable to get something to work. I also really tried to fix the original data I get this from, but it seems like it is not an option.

Any help is appreciated and if possible without any function scripts.
Thank you very much for your time and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("UC"&MAX(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1, ","), "UC(\d+)\s")*1))
```

[image: 0]

**shorter:** `=ARRAYFORMULA("UC"&MAX(LEFT(SPLIT(A1, "UC"), 3)*1))`
**longer:** `=ARRAYFORMULA("UC"&MAX(INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, "UC")), " ")),,1))`